# Positive integers of sum and products

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, factoring, prime-factorization

> Find all pairs of positive integers $m$ and $n$ where $m<n$ such that the sum of $m$ and $n$ added to the product of $m$ and $n$ is equal to $2014$

I just thought about this question and wanted to know how would you solve something like this. Is there a formula that we can use? Is there a certain way we can do this? Out of curiosity, what would the solution look like? Can someone please show me how to do this?

I know the factors of $2014$ are $2*19*53$ and the factors of $2015$ are $5*13*31.$ I know that $mn+m+n$ $=$ $(m+1)(n+1).$ How would I figure out the integers for $m$ and $n$
though. Can someone please help me see the working to this problem and how they would solve a problem like this?

Comment: If $(m+1)(n+1)=2015 = 5\times13\times31$, in how many ways can you factor $2015$ to give positive $m, n$?

Comment: @Macavity There are 8 factors for 2015.

Comment: @Macavity I think I got it now. Thank you.

Comment: Great.  By my count, you should get three pairs.

Comment: @Macavity Yes there are.

Comment: If you understand it now, col, you can write it up and post it as an answer. Later, you can accept that answer.